# Pending Intent does not launch Activity if app is already open or in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent

In my app, i have a widget. If user clicks on widget, I am opening SplashScreen using pending intent using below code.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_main_layout, pendingIntent);
```

This code works fine is app is not open and launch my splash screen.

However if app is already open and in background and if i click on widget then my SplashScreen not opening and instead only app comes to the froeground.

Could anyone let me know whats wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you building `intent`? Have you tried `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`?

Comment: Ohhh I think you  want to open APP each time from splash whenever click on widget . AM i right ?

Comment: Yes. I want to open app each time user clicks widget

Comment: Because your flag is `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, you should change it to `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`

Comment: Please add the code you use to produce the `intent` to your post.

Comment: Also, if the app is already open, what should happen? Should the app restart from the beginning? Please explain exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes. If app is already open, i want app to be restarted from the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers?

Comment: @DavidWasser its not working

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: Does not work in Android 13.

Answer (score 2):

Set the flag of the intent you are passing to the pending `Activity` to:

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: Does not work in Android 13.